# How do I ensure one drop down always has a value of ""

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have 2 drop downs. However, I am trying to make sure that if the user selects a fruit from the fruit menu, then the veg menu is `---`. If the user selects a veg from the veg menu, the the fruit menu is `---`. So no matter what, at least one drop down is `---`.

```js
function event_handler() {
  var Lists = document.getElementByName('fruit')[0];
  Lists.addEventListener('change', reset_menu, false);
}

function reset_menu() {
  alert('test');
}
window.onload = event_handler;
```

```html
<select name="fruit">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
<select name="veg">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
  <option value="carrot">Carrot</option>
  <option value="lettuce">Lettuce</option>
  <option value="cabbage">Cabbage</option>
</select>
```

I am having trouble listening to the menu. I've seen some code where they append to the options, but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the following line of code:

```
list.value = list.options[0].value;
```

This will set the dropdown/select list to be the top value of whatever `list` is ie (`---`). So, when you change the fruit list, you can set `list` to be your `veg` list so that it changes that dropdown list.

Now, when you call your `reset_menu` function you can pass through a list name of which list you wish to reset. Your event handlers manage this so you can define what list name is passed through in those.

See working example below (and code comments for further explanation):

```js
function page_load() {
  var fruitList = document.getElementsByName('fruit')[0];
  fruitList.addEventListener('change', function() {reset_menu("veg")}); // when the fruit list is changed call the reset_menu function to reset the "veg" menu
  
  var vegList = document.getElementsByName('veg')[0];
  vegList.addEventListener('change', function() {reset_menu("fruit")}); // when the vegetable list is changed call the reset_menu function to reset the "veg" menu
}

function reset_menu(listName) {
    var list = document.getElementsByName(listName)[0]; // reset the dropdown list with the name passed through
    list.value = list.options[0].value;
}

window.onload = page_load;
```

```html
<select name="fruit">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
<select name="veg">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
  <option value="carrot">Carrot</option>
  <option value="lettuce">Lettuce</option>
  <option value="cabbage">Cabbage</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the selected option using the `value` attribute of the select-box:

```js
function event_handler() {
  var Lists = document.getElementsByName('fruit')[0];
  Lists.addEventListener('change', reset_menu, false);

  Lists = document.getElementsByName('veg')[0];
  Lists.addEventListener('change', reset_menu, false);
}

function reset_menu() {
  var other = this.name === 'fruit' ? 'veg' : 'fruit';
  document.getElementsByName(other)[0].value = '';
}
window.onload = event_handler;
```

```html
<select name="fruit">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
<select name="veg">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
  <option value="carrot">Carrot</option>
  <option value="lettuce">Lettuce</option>
  <option value="cabbage">Cabbage</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `selectedIndex` of the other select. Like so:

```js
function main() {
  var fruit = document.getElementById('fruit'),
  veg = document.getElementById('veg');
  fruit.addEventListener('change', e => {
    if(fruit.selectedIndex != 0)
      veg.selectedIndex = 0;
  }, false);
  veg.addEventListener('change', e => {
    if(veg.selectedIndex != 0)
     fruit.selectedIndex = 0;
  }, false);
  
}
window.onload = main;
```

```html
<select id="fruit">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
<select id="veg">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
  <option value="carrot">Carrot</option>
  <option value="lettuce">Lettuce</option>
  <option value="cabbage">Cabbage</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Function is `getElementsByName` and it return `NodeList`. To get `item` from a `NodeList` using `index` is as follow

```
 document.getElementsByName('fruits').item(0) // this will get you fruits element
```

Try this

```js
var fruits = document.getElementsByName('fruit').item(0);
var vegs = document.getElementsByName('veg').item(0);

fruits.addEventListener('change', (e) => {  
  vegs.value = e.target.value.length ? "" : vegs.value;
});
vegs.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  fruits.value = e.target.value.length ? "" :fruits.value;
});
```

```html
<select name="fruit">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
<select name="veg">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
    <option value="carrot" >Carrot</option>
    <option value="lettuce" >Lettuce</option>
    <option value="cabbage" >Cabbage</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

## `<select>`

### Changes

- Wrapped a `<fieldset>` around both `<select>s`
- Registered the click event (change event is possible as well) to the `<fieldset>`, now any click to either `<select>` will trigger the callback function `toggleSelect()`. You can add additional `<select>s` and still run with a single `eventListener()`. The demo below has 6 `<select>s`. This method is called [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm).
- Collected the `<select>s` into a NodeList, then an array, then iterated through them with `forEach()`. On each loop, should the `<select>` ***not*** be the one selected ([`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)), and the selected `<select>` has a `value`, it will have a `value` of '', thereby forcing it to select `<option>----</option>`

---

### Demo

```js
var set = document.querySelector('fieldset');

set.addEventListener('click', toggleSelect);

function toggleSelect(e) {
  var sel = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('select'));
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName === 'SELECT') {
    sel.forEach(function(obj, idx) {
      if (obj !== tgt && tgt.value !== '') {
        obj.value = '';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <select name="frt">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  </select>
  <select name="veg">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
    <option value="carrot">Carrot</option>
    <option value="lettuce">Lettuce</option>
    <option value="cabbage">Cabbage</option>
  </select>
  <select name="frt">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  </select>
  <select name="veg">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
    <option value="carrot">Carrot</option>
    <option value="lettuce">Lettuce</option>
    <option value="cabbage">Cabbage</option>
  </select>
  <select name="frt">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  </select>
  <select name="veg">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
    <option value="carrot">Carrot</option>
    <option value="lettuce">Lettuce</option>
    <option value="cabbage">Cabbage</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: If dropdown value is selected empty it should not void the others. Though, your solution is very generic and the right way without any hard coded values .

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way to do this ( if you have only these 2 lists ).

```js
const lists = document.querySelectorAll('select');
lists.forEach((list,i) => {
 list.onchange = function() {
   const resetList = i === 0 ? list.nextElementSibling : list.previousElementSibling;
   resetList.selectedIndex = null;
  }
})
```

```html
<select name="fruit">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
<select name="veg">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---</option>
    <option value="carrot" >Carrot</option>
    <option value="lettuce" >Lettuce</option>
    <option value="cabbage" >Cabbage</option>
</select>
```

If you have more, with this solution you will have to find all the siblings of the selected list